# Firemonkey assign to bitmap after effect

Tags: firemonkey

With FMX, I'm using a standard FMX effect on a TImage and trying to get the bitmap after the effect has been executed - say for example a TColorKeyAlphaEffect. I used the structure pallet to associate the TColorKeyAlphaEffect with the TImage.

When I assign the bitmap of the Timage to another bitmap (or save to file), I only get the original picture prior to the effect - not what is displayed.

Did not find a way to extract the bitmap from the effect itself nor post-effect from the TImage.

Any code for assigning or copying from the TImage to the bmpFinal would do the job and appreciated.

```
bmpFinal.CopyFromBitmap(TImage.picture.graphic, rect(0,0,iWidth, iHeight), 0, 0 );
```

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ***quick response*** you can use `Image1.MakeScreenshot.SaveToFile('yourfilename.ext');`

as ***long*** if (2 Timage involved)
Between 2 images it's easy `Image2.Bitmap:=Image1.MakeScreenshot;`

and you can create effect as runtime i.e

```
uses FMX.Filter.Effects;
 
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var aBitmap : Tbitmap;
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
 begin
   Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(Opendialog1.FileName);
   ABitmap:=Tbitmap.CreateFromFile(Opendialog1.FileName);
   try
     with TmonochromeEffect.Create(nil) do
     try
      ProcessEffect(nil,aBitmap, 0);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
    image2.Bitmap:=ABitmap;
   finally
    aBitmap.Free;
   end;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: latter works perfect.
initial savetofile not really applicable for the implementation.
Thanks!

Comment: Both of your first two suggestions will result in a memory leak of a TBitmap.  MakeScreenshot returns a newly created TBitmap.